# phpmailer body with variables

Tags: php

I'm trying to implement "forgotten pass" php script which generate new password and simply send email to the user. Its all good until the moment that i'm trying to send the new password to the user. I cant include this variable in the body of the email.
I get an error on the line:

```
$mail->body = "The new password is "$newpass"."
```

In my browser im getting

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$newpass' (T_VARIABLE)
```

I know im missing something, but really dont know what...
Any suggestions would be more than welcome

Regards

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Format it like such:

```
$mail->body = "The new password is " . $newpass . ".";
```

You could also use:

```
$mail->body = "The new password is {$newpass}.";
```

PHP has loads of handy String tricks buried in the manual [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Answer (score 2):

You need to concatenate the variable to the string, like:

```
$mail->body = "The new password is " . $newpass . ".";
```

Answer (score 2):

That should be:

```
$mail->body = "The new password is " . $newpass . ".";
```

or

```
$mail->body = "The new password is $newpass.";
```